# modern c++ with clang-tidy causes opposite warnings

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, clang-tidy

this is my 2nd question and i tried to find a matching request and hope i didn't overlooked it this time.

I'm trying to understand modern C++ a little bit more in depth. So a hint was teaching it yourself by using clang and i'm trying it atm but i'm stucked because of one function causing opposite warnings when i try to make it right.

*Background information:* I'm using a singleton pattern which needs to return the only one instance at multiple positions in the source code. This is a simple implementation and i know about possible problems in multi-thread programs. But this is under construction.
The checks are done with build in clang from VSCode-1-73-1 option is --checks=* as recommended by Jason Turner for learning modern C++. The only disabled check is llvmlibc-* because it causes to much trouble with namespaces.

Here is the first warning with source code <**use a trailing return type for this function C/C++ (modernize-use-trailing-return-type)**>:

```
namespace some::own::implementations {

  Example* Example::getInstance() { // <-- hint for getInstance
    static Example _instance;
    return &_instance;
  }

} //  namespace some::own::implementations
```

The interpretation of the error is not hard so i refactored it (including the header part i skipped here) and got the next hint <**a trailing return type is disallowed for this function declaration C/C++ (fuchsia-trailing-return)**>:

```
namespace some::own::implementations {

  auto Example::getInstance() -> Example* { // <-- hint for auto
    static Example _instance;
    return &_instance;
  }

} //  namespace some::own::implementations
```

Ok now i'm a little bit confused whats wrong? Ok one interpretation could be the first hint with modernize-use-trailing-return-type is more general one and fuchsia could be the philosophy of a company or group which was allowed to add the rules to clang and because we can deselect them.

**Questions i have in my mind now:**

1. Is the solution about modernize and fuchsia right?
2. Makes it sense to add opposite warnings to a tool that should or could teach people the right way to implement modern C++ code?
3. If there are different philosophies in the checks (which i don't know atm) which should someone follow who tries to learn modern C++?
4. Whats the right solution for the function?

Comment: I have this personally disabled cause it is annoying and does not always improve readability IMHO.

Comment: You mean fuchsia or clang-tidy in general?

Comment: I mean `modernize-use-trailing-return-type`, I use clang-tidy extensively and this is among the handful checks I have disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're right that Fuchsia is the opinions of a set of developers, and the lint checks are the opinons of a differnet set of developers, and sometimes they're different opinions.

https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/c-cpp/lint clarifies that Fuchsia disables these checks:

```
- clang-diagnostic-unused-command-line-argument - ninja-generated compilation database contains the linker argument, which ends up unused and triggers this warning for every file
- misc-noexcept* - Fuchsia doesn't use C++ exceptions
- misc-non-private-member-variables-in-classes - We don't allow classes/structs with a mix of private and public members, but all public is fine.
- modernize-deprecated-headers - Fuchsia uses old-style C headers
- modernize-use-nodiscard - Not generally used in the Fuchsia codebase
- modernize-raw-string-literal - the check was suggesting to convert \xFF literals, which we'd rather keep in the escaped form.
- modernize-return-braced-init-list - concerns about readability of returning braced initialization list for constructor arguments, prefer to use a constructor explicitly
- modernize-use-emplace - enabled the IgnoreImplicitConstructors option to comply with Abseil Tip of the Week #112.
- modernize-use-equals-delete - flagging all gtest TEST_F
- modernize-use-trailing-return-type - Fuchsia C++ code typically uses the int foo() style of defining functions, and not the auto foo() -> int style as recommended by this check.
- readability-implicit-bool-conversion - Fuchsia C++ code commonly uses implicit bool cast of pointers and numbers
- readability-isolate-declaration - Zircon code commonly uses paired declarations.
- readability-uppercase-literal-suffix - Fuchsia C++ code chooses not to impose a style on this.
```

2. Usually people enable the checks they agree with. It is not expected for someone to enable *all* of the checks.
3. There are indeed different philosophies. You should follow the one you agree with the most.
4. Neither is right. They're both opinions.